# LND seems to ignore CSV delay settings when opening a channel

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels, lncli

LND v0.15.5-beta

In my `lnd.conf` file I have the following lines:

```
bitcoin.maxlocaldelay=144
bitcoin.defaultremotedelay=144
```

When I try to open a channel using `lncli`, I get the following error message:

```
$ lncli --sat_per_vbyte=1 --remote_csv_delay=144 --node_key=XXXXXXXX --local_amt=1500000 --push_amt=750000
[lncli] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = CSV delay too large: 180, max is 144
```

Apparently, it bases its CSV delay value on the size of the channel. Is there any way to override that default? None of the settings or parameters I have tried has worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer this without more information about your setup and your channel partner, but I suspect this is because your channel partner wants a delay of 180, but you've set a `maxlocaldelay` of 144.

Per [the sample conf file from LND](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/5b354c659894c9120660530f691005cc6cf373a0/sample-lnd.conf):

```
; The maximum number of blocks we will limit the wait that our own funds are
; encumbered by in the case when our node unilaterally closes. If a remote peer
; proposes a channel with a delay above this amount, lnd will reject the
; channel.
; bitcoin.maxlocaldelay=2016
```